# Are there any substantive downsides to passwordless "su -l" over passwordless "sudo -i"?

Tags: sudo, password, su

Several years ago I discovered the use of

```
<user|%group> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

in the sudoers file, which allows me to

```
$ sudo -i
#
```

without ever being asked for a password.

For home/personal use machines that don't travel around a lot, aren't exposed to random binaries, and don't store access credentials to anything particularly special, I honestly can't see many downsides.

...Except for the number of characters in `sudo -i`. :)

So I more recently discovered how it's possible to modify `/etc/pam.d/su` and add (or uncomment) the line

```
auth       sufficient pam_wheel.so trust
```

to allow users in the `wheel` group to

```
$ su
#
```

without needing to supply a password.

**So, my question is**... this is kind of cool, but are there any solid reasons I should avoid using `su -l` and stick to `sudo -i` instead?

On the one hand, PAM very obviously supports the use case of passwordless login via `su` (based on the comments present in the `/etc/pam.d/su` shipping in (at least) Debian and Arch), and obviously the option itself has existed for years and isn't going anywhere, and the way it's configured isn't likely to change anytime soon either.

On the other hand, this functionality feels like Little-Known Corner #65,632 in the ad-hoc, multifarious configuration rabbithole known as UNIX, and I can't figure out where to get context on its intended usage.

I was able to Google "passwordless su" once I started wondering if that was possible, but finding comparisons of su vs sudo has proven slightly less cut-and-dried.

So, I thought I'd ask.

Comment: The Monks of The Glorious Su wage eternal war with the Enlightened Masters of Sudo, a war that neither side can ever win.

Comment: I believe it comes down to how you want to manage access to the root account. Since we don't know your requirements, or even what type of Linux system you are maintaining, we can't really say much.

Comment: @Kusalananda: Ah, I had no idea that context factored into my question. It's a personal Debian system being used for simple file server and dev tasks. In terms of root account ownership... I guess I don't really know? (Nobody else is logging into this system yet; the likelihood that'll change is moderate to low.)